# Is it possible to know where the map will stop after a 'dragend' event fires?

Tags: mouseevent, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox-GL-JS fires a `dragend` event after the mouse is released during panning. But at that stage, the map is still moving.

Is it possible to determine from the associated event object what the final resting position of the map will be?

(To be clear, I know about `moveend`, but that fires after the map stops. I'd like to use the time while the map is coasting to a stop to start loading assets that will be required at the location the map will end up in.)